# How can I log out from stackexchange using the tablet?

Tags: discussion

Where is the logout menu on a tablet (e.g. iPad)?

Answer (score 1):

If the Google Chrome developer console is good, this should be here:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It should be there in the **settings** menu.